# Django view problem - Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>":

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-3.7

I have a problem with an order view of my [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) application.

The whole error:

```
Value Error: Cannot assign "SimpleLazyObject: User: wad2": "OrderItem.order"    
must be a "Order" instance.
```

This is the order view:

```
@login_required
def my_order(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {}
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            context['order'] = order
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        context['form']=form
    return render(request, 'iFood/my-order.html', context)
```

The form:

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('created’,)
```

The models for `OrderItem` and `Order`:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='orders')  
    created = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    def __str__(self):
            return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
            return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.id)

        def get_cost(self):
            return self.price * self.quantity
```

The reason I'm using the form is just to confirm the user wants to create the order. I know there's something wrong with the way I create the `OrderItem` and reference order there but I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You use `instance` in a model form when you want to edit an existing instance. If the model form is for `Order`, then the instance must be an order. You are passing a `User` instance, so you get the error.

In your case, you are creating a new order so you don't have to pass an instance. You can save the form with `commit=False`, and then set the user:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.user = request.user
        order.save()
        ...
```

Since you don't get the user to fill in any fields in the form, you could get rid of the form completely. You can still check `request.method`, and that way you will only create the order for `POST` requests.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user)
    ...
```